# Euler method coupled stochastic differential equations with time-derivative

Tags: numerical-methods, stochastic-differential-equations, eulers-method

Given a complex variable $\alpha(t)$ following this stochastic differential equation  $\dot{\alpha}(t)=-\kappa\alpha+\sqrt{\kappa n_{\rm th}} \eta(t)$, where $\eta(t)$ describes a Winer process, we can solve it numerically using Euler-Maruyama method

\begin{equation}
    \alpha(t+dt)=\alpha(t)-\kappa \alpha(t) dt + \sqrt{dt}\sqrt{\kappa n_{\rm th}} W(t)
\end{equation}
where $W(t)$ is sampled from a normal Gaussian distribution.

I am now a bit confused in solving the following coupled equations numerically: $\dot{x}(t)=-\gamma x(t) \dot{\alpha}(t)$. How should I use the Euler method here? Is it correct to use the following equation:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
    &\alpha(t+dt)=\alpha(t)-\kappa \alpha(t) dt + \sqrt{dt}\sqrt{\kappa n_{\rm th}} W(t)\\
    &x(t+dt)=x(t)-\gamma x(t) dt (-\kappa \alpha )-\gamma x(t)\sqrt{\kappa n_{\rm th}}\sqrt{dt}W(t)
\end{split}
\end{equation}

What worries me the most is the integration steps dt and the Wiener increments and that by plugging $\dot{\alpha}$ into $\dot{x}$, there must be some careful steps I am now aware.